# how to select the button after adding by using html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I add some button by using html(), and I want to write a click funtion for them. however, it does not work. and I don't know what is wrong with it.

the html code after using html():

```
    <input type="button" id="save_1" value="a1" />
    <input type="button" id="save_2" value="a2" />
    <input type="button" id="save_3" value="a3" />
```

and my selector is:

```
    $('input[id^=save_]').click(function() {...});
    $('input').on('click', 'id^=save_', function() {...});
```

they all don't work.
could you help me? thank you.

Comment: Have you written click event inside $(document).ready(); ?

Comment: no, my jquery code is : $(function() { $('input[id^=save_]').click(function() {...}); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start from document, input also isn't there when dom is created:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[id^=save_]', function(){
       alert('hi');
    });
```

jsfiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/5egn9m7k/)

Comment: thank you, it works, but I still don't know why? what the different between your suggestion and my code?

Comment: Cause you bind the eventhandler to input, which dont exists when dom is loaded.

document exists when dom is loaded --> document has the active eventhandler which listens to the click event on an input which id starts with save_ -- no matter when or how the input is generated.

If you bind the eventhandler to an input, which dont exists - no eventhandler would be created.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the click event after your `.html()` function else it won't work.

Because if you bind `click` event before `.html()` function it did not get any of the input element (created dynamically) on which you want to bind the `click` event

Comment: like: $('#bt_div').html('<input type="button" id="save_1" value="a1" />').bind('click', function() {...})? and why?

Comment: yes try to create all input elements first using `$('#bt_div').html('<input ..>')` function. and then use `$('input').on('click',function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet: :-)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[id^=save_]').on('click',function() {
   alert("Event Fired");
   });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="save_1" value="a1" />
    <input type="button" id="save_2" value="a2" />
    <input type="button" id="save_3" value="a3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform some operation on click event of all button then add one common class for e.g: class="btn" in all input type button on which you want to perform click event, then use following JS code::

```
$(".btn").on("click",function(){
   $(this).attr("id");
   // your operation
});
```

$(this) will be the button which you have clicked. Make sure this code is written inside document ready function.